# How replicate label in prometheus metric

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

The metric `kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores` from `kube-state-metrics` comes with the labels:

```
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{app="prometheus",chart="prometheus-8.1.0",component="kube-state-metrics",container="autoscaler",heritage="Tiller",instance="10.233.65.93:8080",job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",kubernetes_name="prometheus-kube-state-metrics",kubernetes_namespace="kube-system",kubernetes_node="k8st01",namespace="kube-system",node="k8snode",pod="kubedns-autoscaler-5db95c6cf5-cvqz4",release="prometheus"}
```

I want to make another label pod_name from pod , with the same values. In the end i want to have both `pod="kubedns-autoscaler-5db95c6cf5-cvqz4"` and `pod_name="kubedns-autoscaler-5db95c6cf5-cvqz4"`

I used the followimng

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [pod]
    target_label: pod_name
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `metric_relabel_configs`. Your config block would look something like this:

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [pod]
    target_label: pod_name
```

Comment: it worked thanks. i just read that relabel_config happens before the scrape, and metrics_relabel_configs happens after the scrape